# How to calculate ray in real-world coordinate system from image using projection matrix?

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, projection, matrix-inverse

Given n images and a projection matrix for each image, how can i calculate the ray (line) emitted by each pixel of the images, which is intersecting one of the three planes of the real-world coordinate system? The object captured by the camera is at the same position, just the camera's position is different for each image. That's why there is a separate projection matrix for each image.

As far as my research suggests, this is the inverse of the 3D to 2D projection. Since information is lost when projecting to 2D, it's only possible to calculate the ray (line) in the real-world coordinate system, which is fine.

An example projection matrix P, that a calculated based on given K, R and t component, according to K*[R t]

```
   3310.400000 0.000000 316.730000 
K= 0.000000 3325.500000 200.550000 
   0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 


   -0.14396457836077139000 0.96965263281337499000 0.19760617153779569000 
R= -0.90366580603479685000 -0.04743335255026152200 -0.42560419233334673000 
   -0.40331536459778505000 -0.23984130575212276000 0.88306936201487163000 

   -0.010415508744 
t= -0.0294278883669 
   0.673097816109

   -604.322  3133.973   933.850   178.711
P= -3086.026  -205.840 -1238.247    37.127
   -0.403    -0.240     0.883     0.673
```

I am using the "DinoSparseRing" data set available at http://vision.middlebury.edu/mview/data

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        RealMatrix rotationMatrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(rotationMatrices[i]);
        RealVector translationVector = MatrixUtils.createRealVector(translationMatrices[i]);
        // construct projection matrix according to K*[R t]
        RealMatrix projMatrix = getP(kalibrationMatrices[i], rotationMatrices[i], translationMatrices[i]);
        // getM returns the first 3x3 block of the 3x4 projection matrix
        RealMatrix projMInverse = MatrixUtils.inverse(getM(projMatrix));
        // compute camera center
        RealVector c = rotationMatrix.transpose().scalarMultiply(-1.f).operate(translationVector);

        // compute all unprojected points and direction vector per project point
        for (int m = 0; m < image_m_num_pixel; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < image_n_num_pixel; n++) {
                double[] projectedPoint = new double[]{
                        n,
                        m,
                        1};
                // undo perspective divide
                projectedPoint[0] *= projectedPoint[2];
                projectedPoint[1] *= projectedPoint[2];
                // undo projection by multiplying by inverse:
                RealVector projectedPointVector = MatrixUtils.createRealVector(projectedPoint);
                RealVector unprojectedPointVector = projMInverse.operate(projectedPointVector);

                // compute direction vector
                RealVector directionVector = unprojectedPointVector.subtract(c);
                // normalize direction vector
                double dist = Math.sqrt((directionVector.getEntry(0) * directionVector.getEntry(0))
                        + (directionVector.getEntry(1) * directionVector.getEntry(1))
                        + (directionVector.getEntry(2) * directionVector.getEntry(2)));
                directionVector.setEntry(0, directionVector.getEntry(0) * (1.0 / dist));
                directionVector.setEntry(1, directionVector.getEntry(1) * (1.0 / dist));
                directionVector.setEntry(2, directionVector.getEntry(2) * (1.0 / dist));
            }
        }
    }
```

The following 2 plots show the outer rays for each images (total of 16 images). The blue end is the camera point and the cyan is a bounding box containing the object captured by the camera. One can clearly see the rays projecting back to the object in world coordinate system.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To define the ray you need a start point (which is the camera/eye position) and a direction vector, which can be calculated using any point on the ray.

For a given pixel in the image, you have a projected X and Y (zeroed at the center of the image) but no Z depth value. However the real-world co-ordinates corresponding to all possible depth values for that pixel will all lie on the ray you are trying to calculate, so you can just choose any arbitrary non-zero Z value, since any point on the ray will do.

```
float projectedX = (x - imageCenterX) / (imageWidth * 0.5f);
float projectedY = (y - imageCenterY) / (imageHeight * 0.5f);
float projectedZ = 1.0f; // any arbitrary value
```

Now that you have a 3D projected co-ordinate you can undo the projection by applying the perspective divide in reverse by multiplying X and Y by Z, then multiplying the result by the inverse projection matrix to get the unprojected point.

```
// undo perspective divide (redundant if projectedZ = 1, shown for completeness)
projectedX *= projectedZ;
projectedY *= projectedZ;
Vector3 projectedPoint = new Vector3(projectedX, projectedY, projectedZ);

// undo projection by multiplying by inverse:
Matrix invProjectionMat = projectionMat.inverse();
Vector3 unprojectedPoint = invProjectionMat.multiply(projectedPoint);
```

Subtract the camera position from the unprojected point to get the direction vector from the camera to the point, and then normalize it. (This step assumes that the projection matrix defines both the camera position and orientation, if the position is stored separately then you don't need to do the subtraction)

```
Vector3 directionVector = unprojectedPoint.subtract(cameraPosition);
directionVector.normalize();
```

The ray is defined by the camera position and the normalized direction vector. You can then intersect it with any of the X, Y, Z planes.

Comment: Hi Samgak, thanks a lot for the input. That's a lot of stuff for a beginner in this field. Do you have any concrete formulas? (the projection matrix is a 3x4 matrix, containing k, r and t component)

Comment: I added some pseudo-code to show the general approach

Comment: It's hard to be more specific without knowing exactly what form your projection matrix is in. For example when doing a forward projection and applying the perspective divide, what is the result? Raw screen co-ordinates or some kind of homogenous co-ordinates from -1 to 1 which are then multiplied by screen width/2 and height/2 etc? If so that's something else you need take into account.

Comment: thanks for the pseudo code, i am going through it right now... i also added an example projection matrix in thequestion... K, R and t has been given with the image... i calculated P by myself. Provided with the image, it says "The image origin is top-left, with x increasing horizontally, y vertically". I am talking about the "DinoSparseRing" data set available at http://vision.middlebury.edu/mview/data

Comment: 2 problems: 1.) In order to compute projectionMat.inverse(), a quadratic matrix is needed...  so is it recommended to add 0 0 0 1 as fourth row or take the first 3x3 block of P? On https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projektionsmatrix, this is called the M part of P. 2.) Where to get the camera position from? I bet it's contained in the projection matrix?

Comment: Ok, camera position is: 0=RC+t and C=−(R^T)t

Comment: Looks like you've almost good it going, nice work. If you transform the camera position by the projection matrix, the result should be (0,0,0). So, assuming that the 4x3 matrix is a 3x3 transform matrix concatenated with a 1x3 transform, you can negate the last column (the transform) to create a vector, and then multiply it by the inverse of the 3x3 matrix. This should be the camera position.

Comment: As expected, transforming the camera position vector with the inverse projection matrix, the result is not (0,0,0), so something seems to be wrong. I am not sure if I understand your idea regarding computation of the camera position. What do you mean by 4x3 matrix? I only have a 3x4 matrix which is the projection matrix. I also have a 3x3 rotation matrix and 3x1 vector representing the translation.