# Inverse Camera Intrinsic Matrix for Image Plane at Z = -1

Tags: matrix, camera, hololens, inverse

A similar question was asked before, unfortunately I cannot comment Samgaks answer so I open up a new post with this one. Here is the link to the old question:

[How to calculate ray in real-world coordinate system from image using projection matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224175/how-to-calculate-ray-in-real-world-coordinate-system-from-image-using-projection)

My goal is to map from image coordinates to world coordinates. In fact I am trying to do this with the Camera Intrinsics Parameters of the HoloLens Camera.

Of course this mapping will only give me a ray connecting the Camera Optical Centre and all points, which can lie on that ray. For the mapping from image coordinates to world coordinates we can use the inverse camera matrix which is:

K^-1 = [1/fx 0 -cx/fx; 0 1/fy -cy/fy; 0 0 1]

Pcam = K^-1 * Ppix;

Pcam_x = P_pix_x/fx - cx/fx;

Pcam_y = P_pix_y/fy - cy/fy;

Pcam_z = 1

[Orientation of Camera Coordinate System and Image Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgaWz.png)

In this specific case the image plane is probably at Z = -1 (However, I am a bit uncertain about this). The Section **Pixel to Application-specified Coordinate System** on page [HoloLens CameraProjectionTransform](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mixed-reality/blob/1e5d3036ce48120106af6cd8647c2aaaff21a881/mixed-reality-docs/locatable-camera.md) describes how to go form pixel coordinates to world coordinates. To what I understand two signs in the K^-1 are flipped s.t. we calculate the coordinates as follows:

Pcam_x = (Ppix_x/fx) - (cx*(-1)/fx) = P_pix_x/fx + cx/fx;

Pcam_y = (Ppix_y/fy) - (cy*(-1)/fy) = P_pix_y/fy + cy/fy;

Pcam_z = -1

Pcam = (Pcam_x, Pcam_y, -1)

---

CameraOpticalCentre = (0,0,0)

---

Ray = Pcam - CameraOpticalCentre

---

I do not understand how to create the Camera Intrinsics for the case of the image plane being at a negative Z-coordinate. And I would like to have a mathematical explanation or intuitive understanding of why we have the sign flip (P_pix_x/fx + cx/fx instead of P_pix_x/fx - cx/fx).

Edit: I read in another post that the thirst column of the camera matrix has to be negated for the case that the camera is facing down the negative z-direction. This would explain the sign flip. However, why do we need to change the sign of the third column. I would like to have a intuitive understanding of this.
Here the link to the post [Negation of third column](http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/)

Thanks a lot in advance,
Lisa

Answer (score 0):

> why do we need to change the sign of the third column

To understand why we need to negate the third column of K (i.e. negate the principal points of the intrinsic matrix) let's first understand how to get the pixel coordinates of a 3D point already in the camera coordinates frame. After that, it is easier to understand why -z requires negating things.

let's imagine a Camera c, and one point B in the space (w.r.t. the camera coordinate frame), let's put the camera sensor (i.e. image) at E' as in the image below. Therefore f (in red) will be the focal length and ? (in blue) will be the x coordinate in pixels of B (from the center of the image). To simplify things let's place B at the corner of the field of view (i.e. in the corner of the image)

[image: camera diagram with z positive]

We need to calculate the coordinates of B projected into the sensor d (which is the same as the 2d image). Because the triangles AEB and AE'B' are [similar triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)) then ?/f = X/Z therefore ? = X*f/Z. X*f is the first operation of the K matrix is. We can multiply K*B (with B as a column vector) to check.

This will give us coordinates in pixels w.r.t. the center of the image. Let's imagine the image is size 480x480. Therefore B' will look like this in the image below. Keep in mind that in image coordinates, the y-axis increases going down and the x-axis increases going right.

[image: point B in the image]

In images, the pixel at coordinates 0,0 is in the top left corner, therefore we need to add half of the width of the image to the point we have. then px = X*f/Z + cx. Where cx is the principal point in the x-axis, usually W/2. px = X*f/Z + cx is exactly as doing K * B / Z. So X*f/Z was -240, if we add cx (W/2 = 480/2 = 240) and therefore X*f/Z + cx = 0, same with the Y. The final pixel coordinates in the image are 0,0 (i.e. top left corner)

Now in the case where we use z as negative, when we divide X and Y by Z, because Z is negative, it will change the sign of X and Y, therefore it will be projected to B'' at the opposite quadrant as in the image below.

[image: Camera diagram if z is negative]

Now the second image will instead be:

[image]

Because of this, instead of adding the principal point, we need to **subtract** it. That is the same as negating the last column of K.

So we have 240 - 240 = 0 (where the second 240 is the principal point in x, cx) and the same for Y. The pixel coordinates are 0,0 as in the example when z was positive. If we do not negate the last column we will end up with 480,480 instead of 0,0.

Hope this helped a little bit